# Alignment Issue

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I am creating my resume in LaTeX and loving it, using new commands and learning many new things. However I am stuck at the top. I am trying to create an output like this ..

[image]

I have learnt a bit about indentation and have to learn more about using the `geometry` package but during my coding (below) I am not able to align like the above image. I have used `\noindent` and `\flushright` but each time I use the command the indentation starts with new line making the output different.

[image]

```
%% (c) Shashwat Pant
%% Resume - C.V of Shashwat Pant
%% September 17th 2012

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\noindent \\ \\ \large \bf #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\bf{\huge Shashwat Pant}\\
\end{center}

\hrule

\head{Contact Information}

\begin{center} {

 Address    
} \end{center}

\begin{flushright}
  Voice -

 \end{flushright}

\end{document}
```

Apart from the indentation issue, what font package is good for making resume ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s:

```
%% (c) Shashwat Pant
%% Resume - C.V of Shashwat Pant
%% September 17th 2012

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\noindent \\ \large \bf #1}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\bf{\huge Shashwat Pant}\\
\end{center}

\hrule
\begin{minipage}[c]{.15\textwidth}
\head{Contact Information}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
Address line 1 \\
Line 2 \\
Line 3 \\
Line 4 \\
Line 5
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.3\textwidth}
  Voice -
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

For fonts I have added few choices. Which one is better is a very subjective matter. I prefer charter or palatino or kpfonts.

Comment: Thanks! Was really helpful, will get the `minipage` under my belt asap. Other than that if i don't use `minipage` in the Contact Information field and tried using it on the other two, all the text appears to be bold ? Any guess why ?

Comment: @Shashwat Your `\title` (`\newcommand{\head}[1]{\noindent \\ \large \bf #1}
` is defined to be bold. If you use it within `minipage` it is applicable only inside. Removing `minipage` leaves the command `\bf` open and every thing after that will become bold.

Comment: But I am not including the other text under my `\title` command, so why it is considering the other 2 `minipage` as input ?

Is there a way to create a new scope for contact information without using `minipage` for the first yet keeping the other 2 in `minipage` while keeping the font normal ?

Comment: @Shashwat: Effect of `\bf` will be felt outside the `\head` command also unless you put inside a group. For example put extra set of braces as in `\newcommand{\head}[1]{\par {\large \bf #1}}` and see the effect.

Comment: Could you please remove the image/address. I don't want to put in on internet. Thanks

Comment: @Shashwat No problem! Done.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use tabular-like environments; in the following example I used `tabular` environments inside a `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,draft]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}XlX@{}}
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\huge\bfseries Shashwat Pant} 
\\ \toprule
Contact Information
& 
{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
Address line 1 \\
Address line 2 \\
Address line 3 \\
Address line 4 \\
Address line 5
\end{tabular}
}
&
{
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}l@{}}
  Voice: & \texttt{+}000 99 999 99 \\
  Email: & \texttt{email@gmail.com} \\
  Twitter: & \texttt{shashpant} \\
  GitHub: & \texttt{shashpant}
\end{tabular}
}
\\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unrelated, but useful: never use two consecutive line changing commands `\\ \\` (this will produce underfull boxes warnings); instead of the old `\bf` form, one should use `\bfseries` in modern LaTeX documents.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at tabular representation but can't get hold of some syntax, I prefer to learn the command before implementing so can you please point to some good `tabularx` document.
Other than that when I compile your code I get an awkward placement of the text> I'd really love to use this code, however the awkward alignment and lack of my `geometry` class knowledge makes it worse.

Image/Screenshot http://i.imgur.com/zDCgX.png

Comment: @Shashwat of course; the [tabularx package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf) contains the description of the relevant features. Regarding the problem with your actual code, I would need to see the actual code you are using to see where the problem might be.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and compiled it, all the text appears to be centered right, while I want text to be appear left centered

Comment: @Shashwat something else must be going on in your actual code since my example *as is* doesn't behave like that; again, we need to see the actual code you are using.

Comment: Could you please remove the image/address. I don't want to put in on internet. Thanks

Comment: @Shashwat You should be able to edit here. Note that the data is still in the edit history: you should ask the StackExchange staff to modify this once an edit is made (mods cannot do this).

Comment: @Shashwat done!

Answer (score 2):

Some general comments on the code

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{\noindent \\ \\ \large \bf #1}
```

Try to avoid using `\\` at all, and certainly for adding vertical space, this doesn't add vertical space but rather it adds blank lines (which don't stretch and which do the wrong things at page breaks) To add vertical space use `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`  This command does not use any braces so would make any following text be large and bold. Also `\bf` is a deprecated command only defined in some classes (not in latex itself) for compatibility with the old latex2.09 system.

Better would be

```
\newcommand{\head}[1]{{\par\large \bfseries \noindent#1\par}}
```

You should always make sure if using size change commands that the end of the paragraph is in the scope of the size change, otherwise you get large text on a small baseline and irregular spacing.

```
\begin{center} {
```

LaTeX environments imply grouping so you don't need (and in some cases must not have) the extra `{' group around the environment contents. In this case it is mostly harmless, but it would be better to use simply

```
\begin{center}
```

Each of your environments is a full width display, aligned left right or center, so they come one below the other. You want a three column layout, so the simplest thing is to use a table.

```
\usepackage{array}
```

....

```
   \begin{tabular}{%
     >{\raggedright\large\bfseries}p{3cm}%
     >{\centering}p{5cm}%
     >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}%
     %
Contact Information&
address here .. &
Voice\\
...
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, will keep your tips in mind. As far as `{}` is concerned, its a bad habit from my C++ coding